# code don't change at user side afther changes at the server

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have made some change in the website code at the server and on the client side its reflect but when I made the change in GridView_RowCreated the changes don't reflect at the client side 
i change 'Show' to 'Dbl' like is in the code now.

```
protected void GridViewAllItems_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", " changecolor.call(); this.style.background ='#ffffcc';headColor.call();");
   e.Row.Attributes.Add("ondblclick", "changecolor.call(); this.style.background ='#ffffcc';Ischosen('Dbl'); ");
   hfCurrentIndex.Value = e.Row.TabIndex.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Please edit your post, the code is not readable..

Comment: i have edit the post - us it ok now?